# Android : Start my activity from other activity on long key press of qwerty key

Tags: android, android-activity, key, long-press

I wanna to start my activity on long key press. Where user is on home screen or any other screen.

For an example: Suppose i m on the web browser activity, while watching when user pressed key 'm long press. My app should be start.

Can it is possible to start my activity on long press while user is in other app. (use only qwerty keys not touch key board)...

Please suggest any solution.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna to start my activity on long key press. Where user is on home screen or any other screen.

Generally speaking, that is not possible. You can arrange to have your activity respond to `ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS` for a long press on a search button, for those devices that have a search button.

Comment: thanks dude... i have tried a lot but all in fail. so finally i dropped this topic. thanks for suggestions.